# How can I make pagination run automatically with JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, pagination, setinterval

I needed to use Pagination somewhere on the page. I'll show you the data from the service.

I found a sample. **It works fine, but when I make the created row and window values 7, does not go to page 3. How can I solve this?**

Most importantly, there's something I'd like to add here. I couldn't find a solution.

**I want the buttons in the Pagination section to work automatically. For example, I have 3 pages. Opens on Page 1. I want it to go to Page 2 after 20 seconds and Page 3 after 20 seconds.**

And as for the last page, he needs to go back to Page 1. I'd like to do a 20-second cycle between pages.

Any idea how I can figure it out?

Example code I found:

https://jsfiddle.net/ivanov11/e18zfsau/

*I use these fields as Comment lines*

```
 if (state.page != 1) {
        wrapper.innerHTML = `<button value=${1} class="page btn btn-sm btn-info">&#171; First</button>` + wrapper.innerHTML
    }

    if (state.page != pages) {
        wrapper.innerHTML += `<button value=${pages} class="page btn btn-sm btn-info">Last &#187;</button>`
    }
```

Comment: Off topic: can I suggest you *disable* the first button rather than not show it.   If I want to go page-by-page and click page 2, I have to move the mouse to get to page 3 - this is bad UX.

Comment: Changing your fiddle to rows/window = 7 and it works the same as with 5.  Can you explain what you mean by *"does not go to page 3"*?

Comment: I couldn't show when 3 data remains on the last page, it wants a minimum of 4 data, but it is not very important. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to use `setInterval` to click the next page's button.

```
setInterval(function() {

    var page = state.page + 1;
    var btn = $("button[value=" + page + "]");

    // check if at the end and start again
    if (btn.length == 0)
        btn = $("button[value=1]");

    btn.click();  
}, 20000);
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q8e9fnL0/

A better solution would be to move the click callback code to its own function `function selectPage(page) {...` and call that.  In this case you would need check that the `page` requested is valid otherwise it would keep going with empty pages.  You'd still need a check against max pages (`Math.round(querySet.length / rows);`)

Comment: Thank you, it worked for me. It wasn't my design, it was the interval part I needed.